# BS4 breaks HTML trying to repair it

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

BS4 corrects faulty html. Usually this is not a problem. I tried parsing, altering and saving the html of this page: ulisses-regelwiki.de/index.php/sonderfertigkeiten.html
In this case the repairing changes the representation. After the repairing many lines of the page are no longer centered, but leftaligned instead.
Since I have to work with the broken html of said page, I cannot simply repair the html code.

How can I prevent bs4 from repairing the html or fix the "correction" somehow?

(this minimal example just shows bs4 repairing broken html-code; I couldn't create a minimal example where bs4 does this in a wrong way like with the page mentioned above)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<center>
Some Test content
<!-- A comment -->
<center>
'''

def is_string_only(t):
    return type(t) is NavigableString

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml') #or html.parse

print(str(soup))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this lib.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc

html = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<center>
Some Test content
<!-- A comment -->
<center>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
print (doc.html)
```

Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples

Comment: You are suggesting to use simplified_scrapy instead of bs4 right? Sadly I cannot easily change from bs4 to another lib since the program is indeed way more complex than the minimal example.

Comment: @Natan Send out your complete requirements to see:)

Comment: Mhm. I need to remove certain parts of the html code and add others. All this by accessing certain tags. What I meant above is that changing bs4 would mean changing a lot of code :) so a solution within bs4 would be great. Anyway if you are sure that simplified_scrapy does a better job and can do what I needed to be done, I might have a look.

Comment: @Natan You can use the two together, and you don't have to replace one with the other.

Comment: Thanks :) this might be the point where I should open a new question. I can't figure out how to convert the simplified doc to beautifulsoup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66135288/how-do-i-convert-a-simplified-doc-simplified-scrapy-to-bs4-beautifulsoup-witho maybe you can help me there too :) thanks a lot already!